# Expectation of $1/V(t)$ finite, $V(t)$ strictly positive stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

How can we prove that the expectation of the stochastic process $1/V(t)$, $\forall t \in [0,T]$, is finite?
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E} \left[ 1 / V(t) \right] &<& \infty,
\end{eqnarray}
where $V(t)$ is an stochastic process (mean-reverting):
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    dV(t) &=& \kappa \, (\theta - V(t)) \, dt + \eta \, \sqrt{V(t)} \, dW(t)
    \\
    V(0) &=& v_0 > 0,
\end{eqnarray}
and the parameters are such that the process $V(t)$ has a unique global strong solution (Watanabe-Yamada theorem) and it is strictly positive (Feller condition). We do also assume that:
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T V(t)^2\, dt \right] < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}
(Main idea of the proof). Using Itô's lemma and Dynkin's formula, where $f(x)=1/x$ is a function of class $C^2$ on the interval $\left(0, \infty\right)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E}\left[ f(V(t)) \right] &=& f(V(0)) + \mathbb{E} \int_0^t 
    \Delta f(V(s)) ds \\
    &=& \frac{1}{V(0)} + \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \left( \frac{-\kappa( \theta - 
    V(s))}{V^2(s)} + \frac{\eta^2}{V^2(s)} \right) ds \\
    &=& \frac{1}{V(0)} + \kappa \, \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \frac{1}{V(s)} ds + 
    \left(\eta^2 - \kappa \,\theta \right) \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \frac{1}{V^2(s)} ds.
\end{eqnarray}
By Fubini-Tonelli theorem, we change the order of integration to get
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E}\left[ f(V(t)) \right] &=& \frac{1}{V(0)} + \kappa\int_0^t 
    \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{V(s)} \right] ds + \left(\eta^2 - \kappa \,
    \theta \right) \int_0^t \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{V^2(s)} \right] ds.
\end{eqnarray}
If $\kappa \, \theta \geq \eta^2$, the third term is non-positive and upper bounded by zero, and we have
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{V(t)} \right] &\leq& \frac{1}{v_0} + \kappa 
    \int_0^t 
    \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{V(s)} \right] ds.
\end{eqnarray}
By the Gronwall's inequality, we find the following upper bound, and the claim follows immediately for all $t \in [0,T]$
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
    \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{V(t)} \right] &\leq& \frac{1}{v_0} \, 
    e^{\kappa t} \leq \frac{1}{v_0} \, e^{\kappa T} < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore, the expectation of $1/V(t)$, $\forall t \in [0,T]$, is finite if the parameters $\kappa, \theta, \eta$ of the stochastic process $V(t)$ satisfy $\eta^2 \leq \kappa \, \theta$, which is stronger than the Feller condition ($\eta^2 \leq 2 \, \kappa \, \theta$). Otherwise, $\mathbb{E}\left[ 1/V(t) \right]$ may not be finite? Is it possible to find an upper bound when the inequality $\eta^2 \leq \kappa \, \theta$ is not satisfied? Or at least when the parameters obey the condition $\eta^2 \leq 2 \, \kappa \, \theta$ (weaker condition)?

Comment: Maybe the solution starts by using the Jensen inequality? The function $1/x$ is convex, because $x \sim V(t)$ is strictly positive by assumption and the interval is $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Jensen would give you only a lower bound here. Don't see how that would be of help. I guess I'd start with Ito or Dynkin's formula, respectively.

Comment: This doesn't really help with your question, but I don't think I'd call $V$ an OU process.  The OU process has the form $dV_t = \kappa (\theta - V_t)dt + \eta dW_t$: there's no $\sqrt{V_t}$ in the $dW_t$ term.

Comment: @user6247850 you're wright, it is not an OU process, but I think it is defined as as a sum of squared Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process, as happens with the CIR model?

Comment: @Tobsn could you give more detail about how you would start?

Comment: Apply Ito to $1/V_{t}$ take expectation and see whether you can upper bound the expression.

Comment: @Tobsn that's what I've tried but I think I have done it badly, because then I need to compute E[1/V(t)^2] and E[1/V(t)^3]?

Comment: Show what you did so far.

Comment: @Tobsn If I apply Ito's lemma to $1/V(t)$, I have: 
$d\left(\frac{1}{V(t)}\right) = \frac{-1}{V^2(t)} dV(t) + \frac{1}{V^3(t)} \eta^2 V(t) dt$, that is
$d\left(\frac{1}{V(t)}\right) = \frac{-\kappa \theta}{V^2(t)} dt + \frac{\kappa}{V(t)}dt + \frac{-\kappa \eta}{V^{3/2}(t)} dW(t) + \frac{\eta^2}{V^2(t)}dt$. Now, if I take the expectation, I get:
$d\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{V(t)}\right) = -\kappa \theta \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{V^2(t)}\right] dt + \kappa \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{V(t)}\right] dt + \eta^2 \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{V^2(t)}\right] dt$. How can I continue from here?

Comment: @Tobsn I have added the computations in the question block, so it can be read more clearly

Comment: Typical procedure now would be to appropriately upper bound the rhs and to apply Gronwall inequality. In your case the only troublesome term is the last one. I suggest splitting the integrand off into the part where $X_{s}<1$ and $X_{s}>1$.

Comment: @Tobsn I don't see which would be an upper bound for the expressión
$\frac{1}{V(0)} - \kappa \theta \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \frac{1} {V^2(s)} ds + \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \frac{1}{V(s)} ds + \eta^2 \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \frac{1}{V^2(s)} ds$, or how can we translate into the Gronwall inequality.

Comment: 1 term is no problem, 2nd term can be dropped, 3rd term is what you need for Gronwall for the 4th term I gave a suggestion how to start already

Comment: @Tobsn I think I have understood what you mean (I have rewritten the answer block until this point). But, now we have the same problem but for $\mathbb{E} [1/V^2(t)]$, don't we? My doubt is if the assumptions we have made can translate easily into an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[1/V^2(t)]$, because if we apply Itô's lemma for $1/V^2(t)$ the problem continues.

Comment: Provided $\eta^2<\kappa\theta$ the claim follows immediately from Gronwalls inequality (from your equation under Fubini-Tonelli...). But if that condition is not met things become in fact more delicate. I meant something different with 'splitting the integrand', but as it turns out that ansatz wouldn't be of much help anyway as I've realised now. Is the case $\eta^2>\kappa\theta$ of importance for you?

Comment: @Tobsn In this type of mean-reverting stochastic models (CIR, Heston, etc.) the parameters are assumed to: $(1)$ be non-negative constants $\kappa, \theta, \eta > 0$; $(2)$ do obey the Feller condition $2 \kappa \theta \geq \eta^2$, so $V(t)$ is strictly positive; and $(3)$ the model has a unique global strong solution by the Watanabe-Yamada theorem. According from what you have explained, we are in the "good" situation? Why it follows inmediately from Gronwall's inequality?

Comment: @Tobsn Then, we will have the following expression: 
$\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{V(t)} \right] \leq \frac{1}{V(0)} + K_1 e^{t} + K_2e^{\left(\eta^2 - \kappa \theta \right)t}$. And, according from what you explained, this can be said to be finite? (Taking into account what we assumed with respect to the parameters)

Comment: If $\eta^2<\kappa\theta$, then $\mathbb{E}[1/V_{t}]\le 1/\nu_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}[1/V_{s}]ds$, whence by Grownwall $\mathbb{E}1/V_{t}\le 1/\nu_{0}e^t\le1/\nu_{0}e^T<\infty$

Comment: @Tobsn Perfect!! I see what you have done. One more question, $\eta^2 < \kappa \, \theta$ is what we need for the third term to be zero. Howeever, the model assumes  this inequality $\eta^2 < 2 \, \kappa \, \theta$. I think is okay too, as $\eta, \kappa, \theta > 0$, don't?

Comment: It's not all correct in the way you've written it down. The second integral term is not necessaryly zero but its non-positive and therefore bounded from above by zero. Also, you've got to read carefully how Gronwall is applied. Your second last chain of inequalities is wrong. Finally, the bound only applies if $\eta^{2}\le\kappa\theta$ which is a stronger condition than $\eta^{2}\le 2\kappa\theta$.

Comment: @Tobsn you are totally right, hope now it's correct.

Comment: @Tobsn I have been reviewing the calculus and I think that the upper bound is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{V(t)} \right] \leq \frac{1}{v_0} \, e^{\kappa t} \leq \frac{1}{v_0} \, e^{\kappa T} < \infty.$ (note that $\kappa$ have to be in the exponent, don't?